"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" in DataTables format function when accessing child row
Problem:
I'm trying to display detailed information about each teacher's qualifications in a DataTables row expansion using JavaScript. The server-side code in ASP.NET Core returns a JSON object containing the list of teachers and their qualifications, which includes a nested object for each qualification's grade details.
However, when I try to expand a teacher's row in the DataTable, I get the following JavaScript error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
  
    let result = `<div></div>`;
    result += "<table>";

    if (d.TeacherQualifications && d.TeacherQualifications.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < d.TeacherQualifications.length; i++) {
            const qualification = d.TeacherQualifications[i];

            result += "<tr><td><strong>Institution:</strong></td><td>" + qualification.institution + "</td></tr>";
            result += "<tr><td><strong>Year Of Completion:</strong></td><td>" + qualification.yearOfCompletion + "</td></tr>";
            result += "<tr><td><strong>Grade :</strong></td><td>" + (qualification.grade?.name || 'N/A') + "</td></tr>";
            result += "<tr><td><strong>Description:</strong></td><td>" + (qualification.grade?.description || 'N/A') + "</td></tr>";

            if (i < d.TeacherQualifications.length - 1) {
                result += "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        result += "<tr><td colspan='2'>No qualifications available.</td></tr>";
    }

    result += "</table>";
    return result;
}


public IActionResult GetTeachers()
{
    var teachers = _context.Teachers
        .Include(x => x.TeacherQualifications)
        .ThenInclude(g => g.Grade)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.Name,
            x.FatherName,
            x.Cnic,
            x.Email,
            x.DateOfBirth,
            x.DateOfJoin,
            TeacherQualifications = x.TeacherQualifications.Select(q => new
            {
                q.Institution,
                q.YearOfCompletion,
                Grade = new
                {
                    q.Grade.Name,
                    q.Grade.Description
                }
            }).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();

    return Json(new { data = teachers });
}````


Troubleshoot steps
To debug this issue, we need to open the browser developer tools and check whether d.TeacherQualifications is NULL. If it is NULL, you will encounter the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length').
Suggestions
Please change your GetTeachers method like below.
public IActionResult GetTeachers()
{
    var teachers = _context.Teachers
        .Include(x => x.TeacherQualifications)
        .ThenInclude(g => g.Grade)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.Name,
            x.FatherName,
            x.Cnic,
            x.Email,
            x.DateOfBirth,
            x.DateOfJoin,
            TeacherQualifications = (x.TeacherQualifications ?? new List<TeacherQualification>()).Select(q => new
            {
                q.Institution,
                q.YearOfCompletion,
                Grade = q.Grade != null ? new
                {
                    q.Grade.Name,
                    q.Grade.Description
                } : null
            }).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();

    return Json(new { data = teachers });
}

And change your javacript code.
let result = `<div></div>`;
result += "<table>";

if (Array.isArray(d.TeacherQualifications) && d.TeacherQualifications.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < d.TeacherQualifications.length; i++) {
        const qualification = d.TeacherQualifications[i];

        result += "<tr><td><strong>Institution:</strong></td><td>" + (qualification.institution || 'N/A') + "</td></tr>";
        result += "<tr><td><strong>Year Of Completion:</strong></td><td>" + (qualification.yearOfCompletion || 'N/A') + "</td></tr>";
        result += "<tr><td><strong>Grade :</strong></td><td>" + (qualification.grade?.name || 'N/A') + "</td></tr>";
        result += "<tr><td><strong>Description:</strong></td><td>" + (qualification.grade?.description || 'N/A') + "</td></tr>";

        if (i < d.TeacherQualifications.length - 1) {
            result += "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        }
    }
} else {
    result += "<tr><td colspan='2'>No qualifications available.</td></tr>";
}

result += "</table>";
return result;

